# ESD protection for work with CPU/GPU

Tags: cpu, esd, bga, gpu

I am ready to perform a BGA reballing operation on my ps3's CPU and GPU chips. Should i take into consideration electrostatic discharge or is it not needed?

How can i protect from these dangers? Are there special gloves to buy? Or i saw in a pic a guy wearing a bracelet, maybe one of these? Do these work in isolation?

Comment: If you need to ask these questions and want to attempt a BGA repair, then all I can do is to wish you good luck, you will need it.

Comment: To cite Illidan Stormrage: "You are not prepared!", on a more serious note: [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22474/to-avoid-esd-when-you-are-working-on-computers-what-should-you-attach-your-wris) question and especially the not accepted answer might provide some insight on ESD protection, which you should take into account for all work on electronic devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer is yes, you should always take into consideration ESD risks.

You should have an ESD protected surface and a ground strap (there is some argument for ESD protection gloves, but you don't see them in use much, at least I haven't seen them used much in industry).

The ground mat (like this one:  [Maplin anti-static mat](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/small-anti-static-mat-300-mm-x-550-mm-n68ea)) is the most important bit (IMO) as you can us that to give yourself a good grounding to reduce your ESD. But you have to make sure the matt itself is grounded, that is the most important bit, any expense on ESD protection is wasted unless you have a good route to ground.

Many bits of ESD protection (such as the one linked to) have clips to attach to a "good ground", but you can also get plugs (like in this kit: [Maplin anti-static kit](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/field-service-engineers-kit-595-mm-x-595-mm-ja62s)) which would be my preferred option.

But I would say that re-balling a BGA is a very risky operation anyway, I would be more worried about that than the ESD risk.